# C++ Container for high performance FIFO

Tags: c++, stl

I need to optimize some legacy code and am fairly new to C++.

The code does network packet processing in two threads, one thread pushing packets to a FIFO [`topupBuffer`] and the other thread reading from the queue and sending them out an IP socket [`writeToIPOutput`]. The legacy code uses std::deque to implement the FIFO.

However, running the program uses a lot of CPU, up to 50% (where it needs to be more like 5%).  Running gprof seems to reveal `std::deque` is the culprit.  (I am not sure I am interpreting the profile results correctly, so help is appreciated)

Excepts from the profile output:
**topupBuffer hierarchy:**

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.65    2.51       1/1           DvIPFilePlayback::topupBufferThreadMethod(void*) [2]
[1]     60.5    0.65    2.51       1         DvIPFilePlayback::topupBuffer() [1]
                0.27    1.15 4025575/4025575     DvIPPlaybackBC::bufferizeTsPackets(TPlaybackBuffer&, int&, int&) [5]
                0.03    0.56 4026668/4026668     std::deque<TTsPacket, std::allocator<TTsPacket> >::push_back(TTsPacket const&) [6]
                0.03    0.15 4046539/5749754     std::deque<TPlaybackBuffer, std::allocator<TPlaybackBuffer> >::size() const [17]
```

and

```
[5]     27.2    0.27    1.15 4025575         DvIPPlaybackBC::bufferizeTsPackets(TPlaybackBuffer&, int&, int&) [5]
                0.04    0.30 4031674/4031674     std::deque<TTsPacket, std::allocator<TTsPacket> >::pop_front() [11]
                0.03    0.30 8058004/8058004     std::deque<TTsPacket, std::allocator<TTsPacket> >::size() const [12]
                0.01    0.19  576183/576183      DvPlaybackBC::insertToPlaybackBuffer(TPlaybackBuffer const&) [22]
                0.04    0.11 4029401/4029401     std::deque<TTsPacket, std::allocator<TTsPacket> >::front() [25]
```

**writeToIPOutput Hierarchy**

```
[3]     36.8    0.92    1.00       1         DvIPPlaybackBC::writeToIPOutput() [3]
                0.31    0.00 1129444/1129444     TPlaybackBuffer::operator=(TPlaybackBuffer const&) [13]
                0.01    0.18  579235/1155128     std::deque<TPlaybackBuffer, std::allocator<TPlaybackBuffer> >::push_back(TPlaybackBuffer const&) [8]
                0.03    0.10 1135318/1135318     std::deque<TPlaybackBuffer, std::allocator<TPlaybackBuffer> >::pop_front() [27]
```

I guess `writeToIPOutput` spends too much time on assignment.  I can work on that.  But `topupBuffer` spends it's time in `std::deque`.

Is that the correct interpretation of the profile output?

If so, then is using a different container going to be more efficient and, if so, which one?

Thank you

**EDIT I**
The explanatory notes at the end of the call tree says:

```
% time  This is the percentage of the `total' time that was spent
        in this function and its children.  Note that due to
        different viewpoints, functions excluded by options, etc,
        these numbers will NOT add up to 100%.

self    This is the total amount of time spent in this function.

children    This is the total amount of time propagated into this
        function by its children.
```

So looking at `bufferizeTsPackets`, 1.15 is spent in its children, of which, 0.30 + 0.30 + 0.11 = 0.71 is spent in different deque methods (push_back, size etc).  Right?  So 0.71 is over half of the total time (1.15) spent in in the children (??)

Comment: Have you tried using our beloved friend, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? For FIFO, though mundane, but you may want to consider [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) with a vector as the underlying container

Comment: I wonder if a [`boost::lockfree::queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) would work better.

Comment: Try making each item in the `deque` be a short vector of work items, that way you don't have as many operations on the shared data structure.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. Not my code and original developer long gone. Being new to C++ isn't helping either :-)

Comment: I am not sure if your interpretation is correct: `std::deque` self+children numbers are not on the top, and most of the time in them is spent in the allocator. You should be able to get more improvements from optimizing your part of the code to the point when `std::deque` start topping the list.

Comment: The items in the queue are MPEG transport stream packets, approx 200bytes each. Could be several thousand in the queue. After "processing", writeToIPOutput writes 7 at a time to a UDP datagrams.

Comment: looking at [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Call-Graph.html#Call-Graph) It seems that your functions are busy all by themselves, and that deque has nothing to do with your problem; in that you've got a low number of ms/call for the deque commands, but high for your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient structure would be to implement a circular queue (ring buffer) using an array.

Since arrays are fixed size, you either have to make the array large enough so there is no data overrun; or only store the last N values, where N is the capacity of the buffer.

Many embedded systems use arrays to reduce any issues of memory fragmentation caused by dynamic memory location.

If your array is small enough, it can fit in the processor's data cache; which speeds up computation.

Comment: After fiddling around for a long time, I implemented a flat, fixed size C-style array holding the structs and made in an interface to make it *look* like a deque.  Much better now!